# new Blender version 2.8 not working on win7 64bit

Tags: game-engine

I have downloaded the new version of Blender 2.8 on my desktop I can see Blender starting up a gray window opens and then just shuts down.

Comment: Check system requirements before installing . That goes for any software.

Comment: The minimum requirements are documented here: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ If your hardware fulfills the requirements, try to update your graphics driver to a more recent version.

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/ if you think it can be a bug reporter here

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on a pc x5675 older system, by installing blender 2.81 experimental.  It may have some extra bug fixes that may help you. Apparently the release for stable is in November.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have the same problem. I think that it may be the intel graphics card. If you update it to support of openCL 3.3 or more recent, then it should work.